# Graphite & Grafana with htaccess user+password

Tags: graphite, grafana

I've set up a graphite and grafana instance, both on the same machine, but with different vhosts (using Apache) to be able to access both independently from each other.

It runs fine, but as soon as I try to put up a basic authentication on the graphite instance, grafana cannot read the data anymore. I've modified the config.js source from Grafana to include the username and password for the graphite instance (as seen in the snippet below).

When I open the Grafana row editor, I see the renderer not using the username + password (in reuqest -> url). I see there:

http://graphite.my-server.de:80/render

How can have Grafana use the username+password to access graphite?

Thanks!!

```
// Graphite & Elasticsearch example setup
datasources: {
  graphite: {
    type: 'graphite',
    url: "http://adminuser:mypassword@graphite.my-server.de:80",
  },
  elasticsearch: {
    type: 'elasticsearch',
    url: "http://adminuser:mypassword@graphite.my-server.de:9200",
    index: 'grafana-dash',
    grafanaDB: true,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your browser cache config.js with previous settings. 
Try to use clear cache or use another browser.

And, are you sure that elasticsearch have the same basic auth login and password?

Comment: And it good time to try grafana v2.0 with more simplest architecture. (:

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with an apache setting. Debugging with Google Chrome and the dev tools plugin showed the issue. Needed to add those headers:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://grafana.my-server.de"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept"
```